# Code Skips Until NSTask Completes

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I am creating a little shredder application for the Mac using Cocoa that securely erases files. I am running code every time my NSTask receives data to update some UI elements. The problem is some things (files remaining label, setting the progress bar to 0, bringing the window to the foreground) aren't working until the NSTask completes.  This code is activated when a file is dropped in my window.

```
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    int filesRemain = 0;

    NSPasteboard *pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];

    NSArray *files = [pboard propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType];
    NSMutableArray *args = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [args addObject:@"-rfv"];
    for(NSString * myStr in files) {
        [args addObject:myStr];
        filesRemain ++;
    }
    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];

    task.launchPath = @"/usr/bin/srm";

    task.arguments  = args;

    NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];
    [task launch];
    NSLog(@"task launched");
    while ([task isRunning])
    {
        NSData* data = [[pipe fileHandleForReading] availableData];
        NSString *string;
        string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if ([string hasSuffix:@"%"]) {
            NSString *numberString;
            NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
            NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
            [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:NULL];
            [scanner scanCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&numberString];
            int number = [numberString intValue];
            [progIndicator setDoubleValue:number];
            [progText setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Files Remaining", filesRemain]];
        } else if (!([string rangeOfString:@"done"].location == NSNotFound)) {
            filesRemain --;
            [progIndicator setDoubleValue:100];
            if (filesRemain == 0) {
                NSLog(@"process completed");
                [dropWindow setAlphaValue:1];
                [progressView setAlphaValue:0];
            } else {
                [progIndicator setDoubleValue:0];
            }
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Is there any way to prevent this code skipping? Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some problems with this code:

⑴ You’re blocking the main thread in your while() loop, so nothing will display until that’s done, and the app will lock up and the user won’t be able to enter input. You could fix that by adding a call to -display the view(s) in question every time, but please don’t, because there are other issues, like

⑵ You’re polling for data from the task as fast as the loop can execute, without any delay between attempts, so you’re absolutely burning the user’s battery. The CPU is VERY fast, it can process BILLIONS of instructions a second, so this loop is going to start spinning very fast, much faster than the task can produce output, and it’ll be updating all the progress meters like crazy.

⑶ You don’t check if there’s available data before you ask for availableData, so your app could pause an indefinite amount of time while it waits for the task to finish.

---

There are several ways to solve these issues. The most modern and best way is to set the fileHandle’s `readabilityHandler` to a block that schedules an update of your UI on the main thread, and then immediately return from the method above so the main run loop regains control and displays happen.

Note that (from the docs) it looks like your readabilityHandler will be called from arbitrary threads, so you don’t want to modify any unprotected instance variables or make any UI calls from it directly. What you can do is use it to schedule an update of the UI on the main thread, something like this:

```
NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];
[task launch];
pipe.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = ^{
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSString *const string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        // ...
        // update UI code
        // ...
    };
};
```

Comment: Set a block on the NSTask’s `terminationHandler`.